# Zune desktop software doesnt detect nokia lumia 520 in windows 8 os

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

I bought a nokia lumia 520 recently.
I have windows 7 phone SDK installed and I am trying to register the lumia 520 with microsoft.

Zune software doesnt detect the device...
Does anybody face this issue or any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

The Lumia 520 is running Windows Phone 8.

You'll need to install the [Windows Phone 8 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471).

As for the Zune Media Software, this does not support Windows Phone 8. To sync media to your phone, you'll need to use the [Windows Phone app for Desktop](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-AU/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop).

Comment: I was under the impression that Zune wasn't even supported under Windows 8.

Comment: @Ramhound not as a Metro app, but you can still run it as a desktop application.